Why am I unable to import Resilience4J Retry in my application?
I am trying to implement the resilience4j retry into my application. I have already implemented circuit-breaker and it was imported just fine - however, I am unable to implement retries and I am not sure why that is.
build.gradle
implementation("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot3:2.2.0")
implementation("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-circuitbreaker:2.2.0")
implementation("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-retry:2.2.0")

application.yml
# Circuit Breaker
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
   confgs:
      default:
         failureRateThreshold: 20

# Retry
resilience4j.retry:
   configs:
      default:
         maxAttempts: 3
         waitDuration: 100
      instances:
         myFun:
            baseConfig: default

Now, in my application, I am trying to add the @Retry annotation to the function that makes an REST request, but I'm getting an error when I attempt to import the retry module.
import io.github.resilience4j.retry
I am not able to post images as my reputation is too low. However, when I attempt to import the above, I receive an unresolved reference error as if it cannot find the module.
https://i.imgur.com/4eHCDir.png
I imported the dependency for the retry, set up the configuration, and attempted to import it into my application. I verified that I am using the correct R4J versions and have rebuilt my project several times but to no avail.

Why not use the Retry mechanism from spring itself? Here is an article about it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry

By adding this dependency in Pom.xml worked for me
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot3</artifactId>
</dependency>

